# Possible values of $\gcd(a+b, a\times b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, problem-solving, factoring

> **Main Question:** Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> What are the possible values of $\gcd(a+b, a\times b)$ given that $\gcd(a,b) = N$?

**Fact 0.** If  $\gcd(a,b) = N$, then $N \leq \gcd(a+b, a\times b) \leq N^2$.

More substantially:

**Fact 1. (D. Fischer below).**

Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$. For every $d$ a divisor of $N$, there are natural numbers $a, b$ for which $\gcd(a,b) = N$ and $\gcd(a+b, a\times b) = dN$. Moreover, these are precisely the values that $\gcd(a+b, a\times b)$ can take on provided that $\gcd(a,b) = N$.

Comment: Conjecture 0 is correct, conjecture 1 wrong. Write $a = N\cdot \alpha$ and $b = N\cdot \beta$. What do you know about $\gcd(\alpha,\beta)$ if $\gcd(a,b) = N$, what can you deduce about $\gcd(\alpha+\beta,N\alpha\beta)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Okay; working out an example. Let $N = 3$; let $a = 3 \cdot 2$ and $b = 3 \cdot 5$. Then $\gcd(2, 5) = 1$ (and $\gcd(6, 15) = 3$ as desired). Now $\gcd(7, 21) = 7$. I have the sense that I'm overlooking something obvious, but I do not see the issue with the above. For $N = 3$, there are certainly $a,b$ such that $\gcd(+, \times) = 3, 6, 9$. Are you indicating other values can be taken on, too? (More generally: Should the answer to the **main question** be clear? I do not see it...)

Comment: Where do you get the $6$ from (for $N = 3$)?

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, I had miscalculated; I had thought $a = 6$ and $b = 30$ worked, but I see now that $\gcd(+, \times) = 36$ (and *not*, as I had thought, $6$). So you have found the clear error that I worried existed in the latter conjecture; *thank you*. Do you see how to resolve the initial question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us write $a = N\cdot \alpha$ and $b = N\cdot \beta$, where $N = \gcd(a,b)$. Then we have $\gcd(\alpha,\beta) = 1$ (for $N\cdot \gcd(\alpha,\beta)$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$). Further,

$$\gcd(a+b,a\cdot b) = \gcd(N(\alpha+\beta),N^2\alpha\beta) = N\cdot \gcd(\alpha+\beta,N\alpha\beta).$$

Now we note that $\gcd(\alpha+\beta,\alpha\beta) = 1$ (why?), and from that deduce

$$\gcd(a+b,ab) = N\cdot \gcd(\alpha+\beta,N).$$

It follows that $\gcd(a+b,ab)$ is always of the form $N\cdot d$, where $d$ is a divisor of $N$.

It remains to see that every $N\cdot d$ where $d\mid N$ can be such a $\gcd$. For $d = 1$, take $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = N$, for $d > 1$, take $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = d-1$.

Comment: This is great; thanks!